# Is it possible to add an XML "log" using CustomXMLParts in Excel VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have project that require I maintain log of users (using `Application.UserName`) that perform a certain actions with a macro-enabled Excel spreadsheet.  I've tried using the VB examples found at the links list below and modifying for VBA, but I'm running into error at last line of `Sub`.  Can anyone point me towards a better VBA example or guide me in the right direction?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608627.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb608612.aspx

Here's the code I'm currently working with.

```
Private Sub AddCustomXmlPartToWorkbook(ByVal Workbook As Excel.Workbook)
    Dim xmlString As String
    xmlString = _
        "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""utf-8"" ?>" & _
            "<employees xmlns=""http://schemas.microsoft.com/vsto/samples"">" & _
                "<employee>" & _
                    "<name>Karina Leal</name>" & _
                    "<hireDate>1999-04-01</hireDate>" & _
                    "<title>Manager</title>" & _
                "</employee>" & _
            "</employees>"
    Dim employeeXMLPart As Office.CustomXMLPart
    employeeXMLPart = ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just run the statement that adds the CustomXMLPart:

```
Call ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Add(xmlString)
```

It is added to the end of the collection, so you know it's position by doing `ActiveWorkbook.CustomXMLParts.Count`

Comment: Thanks @Nybbe!  That worked perfect.  One addition question, when verifying it worked, I noticed it created new `Item` in folder each time.  Is it possible to instead add to an existing item?  If not, that's okay, it work great already.  Thanks again.

Comment: Sorry, dont know that. I see that referring to CustomXMLParst(index) gives you just a read-only access. So I guess you would have to read the old one and manually join the old one with your new and then delete the old one and add your newly created... But this is just a guess...